# Symfony&Doctrine2: Value of `mappedBy` annotation?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am learning Symfony 3 with Doctrine 2.

When I have `OneToMany` relationship in Doctrine entity, what **exactly** I have to put into `mappedBy` annotation?

- Is it the *table name* of current entity?
- Or is it the *entity shortcut*?
- Or is it the actual class name?

Imagine this simple example:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog_category")
 */
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $articles;

    // ...

}
```

Why is the *"category"* correct value for `mappedBy`? Why isn't it *"blog_category"* or *"Category"* (uppercase "C")? Or *"AppBundle:Category"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I figured it out. It is the name of related's entity class variable :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To give a complement, almost everything you could do in doctrine (could surely be applied for any other ORM/ODM), in almost every contexts (QueryBuilder, findBy methods, ...) you'll use *property* names rather than *column* names.

The reason is quite simple, an ORM deals with objects and their properties, abstracting the real tables and their columns, no matter of the database engine or anything else.